# How FIX Protocol handles chain of request

Tags: fix-protocol

I have a question regarding FIX Protocol and I'm quite new to it.

A client sent an order and it got accepted by the broker. After that, the client sent a request (request #1) to modify the quantity to x. However, before request #1 is accepted, the client sent another modification request (request #2) to modify the quantity to y.

I search the documentation of FIX Protocol and find these.

> - The order sender should chain client order ids on an ‘optimistic' basis, i.e. set the OrigClOrdID <41> to the last non rejected ClOrdID <11> sent
> - The order receiver should chain client order ids on a ‘pessimistic' basis, i.e. set the OrigClOrdID <41> on execution reports that convey the receipt or succesful application of a cancel/replace and Order Cancel Reject <9> messages to be the last ‘accepted' ClOrdID <11> (See "Order State Change Matrices" for examples of this)

However, I still don't understand how FIX Protocol handles request. Will the quantity be modified to y? Or does it depend on which request is being accepted last?

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand that the FIX Protocol is a set of guidelines on how someone who implements the protocol **should** handle certain scenarios. In practice there are differences in how counterparties handle this.

In your example the quantity should be modified to **y** in the end. But the quantity will be modified to **x** first since that message was received at first.

Here are some chaining examples taken from the spec:
https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/app_d.html (search for **sequencing** or **chaining**)

Here are examples specific to your question where two consecutive replace requests are handled:
https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/app_dD.2.a.html
https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/app_dD.2.b.html